# Rails searching a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise

Heyo. Been trying to figure this out but I've been stuck too long and it's just getting painful!

I'm trying to do an Advanced Search form allowing you to search for Users based off settings that are in other models. e.g. Search for a User named Jim, who does Running, and has weight loss as his goal.

I have three models:

- User (using Devise)
- Sport (many-to-many with user)
- Goals (user has_many goals, goal belongs_to user)

So far I have managed to get it working so I can search for things in the User model (such as name) and also for Users Sports through a select box. What I haven't been able to get working is searching for the Users goals and I don't get why.

What I get is "Nobody seems to have these preferences" when searching ONLY for Goals and no other fields.

I have tried using the same code as my Sports but that didn't work (guessing because of the different relationships?)

```
# searches/show.html.erb
<% if @search.search_users.empty? %>

  <p>Nobody seems to have these preferences</p>

<% else %>
<% @search.search_users.each do |u| %>
  <tr>
   <td><%= u.name %></td>

    <% u.sports.each do |s| %>
     <td><%= s.name %></td>
    <% end %>

    <% u.goals.each do |g| %>
     <td><%= g.name %></td>
    <% end %>

  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I've done associations in the console and when I type for example u.goals I get this (and the opposite when I query what users are associated with a goal):

```
irb(main):015:0> u.goals
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Goal id: 1, name: "Weight Loss", user_id: 1>, #<Goal id: 3, name: "Strength", user_id: 1>]>
```

Here's my current code:

```
# user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_and_belongs_to_many :sports
 has_many :goals, :foreign_key => :goal_id
end

# sport.rb
class Sport < ApplicationRecord
 has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

# goal.rb
class Goal < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :goal_id
end
```

And my searches stuff:

```
# search.rb
def search_users
 users = User.all
 users = users.where("users.name ILIKE ?", "%#{keywords}%") if  keywords.present?
 users = users.joins(:sports).where("sports.name ILIKE ?", "%#{name}%") if name.present?
 users = users.where(goal_id: goal_id) if goal_id.present?
 return users
end

# searches/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @search do |s| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= s.label :keywords %>
    <%= s.text_field :keywords %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= s.label :exercise %>
    <%= s.select :name, options_for_select(@s_names), include_blank: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= s.label :goals %>
    <%= s.collection_select :goal_id, Goal.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
  </div>
  <%= s.submit "Search", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>

# searches_controller.rb
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @search = Search.new
    @s_names = Sport.uniq.pluck(:name)
    @users = User.uniq.pluck(:name)
  end

   def create
    @search = Search.create(search_params)
    redirect_to @search
  end

  def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def search_params
   params.require(:search).permit(:keywords, :name, :goal_id)
 end
end
```

and then my schema for reference:

```
create_table "goals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_goals_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "searches", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "keywords"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "goal_id"
    t.index ["goal_id"], name: "index_searches_on_goal_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "sports", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "sports_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id",  null: false
    t.integer "sport_id", null: false
    t.index ["user_id", "sport_id"], name: "index_sports_users_on_user_id_and_sport_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "movement_id"
    t.integer  "goal_id"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["goal_id"], name: "index_users_on_goal_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

  add_foreign_key "goals", "users"
end
```

Extremely sorry for the huge amount of messy code but I'm just tripping over myself at this point and getting confused.

Thank you greatly in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change

```
users = users.where(goal_id: goal_id) if goal_id.present?
```

To

```
users = users.joins(:goals).where(goals: {id: goal_id})
```

For advanced searching I've recently used approach presented in this article: http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/search-and-filter-rails-models-without-bloating-your-controller/ and I think it's worth reading if you think about expanding search options.

**EDIT: full response in comments below**
`:foreign_key => :goal_id` needed to be removed

Comment: Thanks for your response! I get this error when doing that: "PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column goals.goal_id does not exist". but it's there in my db..

Comment: I've checked my code and it looks like this: `where(:goals=> {:id => goal_id})` to be exact.

Comment: But both syntax should be correct.
Problem is with your custom foreign key. Remove  `:foreign_key => :goal_id` from both models. From your migration looks like there's no such column. PK for table goals should be just 'id', not 'goal_id'. It tries to `SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN goals ON goals.goal_id = users.id` and it doesn't make sense. By removing those foreign_key clauses rails will know that it should look for user_id in table goals. Generated SQL for joins should look `SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN goals ON goals.user_id = users.id`

Comment: Thank you so much! I was just going round in circles making my code messier and messier. It now works. Get's really hard to figure out what's gone wrong when it ends up like this haha. Appreciate it, marked it as the answer now :)

Comment: Great, happy to help :). The thing you have to remember about RoR is that fighting convention always results in casualties and specifying custom foreign_key is one of these things which break RoR convention (at least in simple relations, multiple relation to same table needs different approach).